# Is one book long enough to make my character fall in love?

Tags: character-development, romance

I am new to writing and this is my first story. I want to make my story believable and was wondering if one book is long enough to make my character fall head-over-heels for someone. She has known the love interest for quite some time but didn't think much of him because she was in a relationship with someone else. She breaks up with the previous guy because she is dealing with trauma, and then falls in love with the current love interest.

I don't plan on her realizing her feeling for him until the last book. Will one book be enough for her to go from liking him to being head-over-heels in love with him?

Comment: Pretty sure the vastly successful market of stand alone romance novels speaks for itself.

Comment: One chapter is enough. In fact, since they already knew each other, you could establish it as a fact with one or two sentences. "She looked over at him smiling in that smarmy way he always did, running his hands through his hair, and she realized with a start that she loved the stupid, arrogant fool. She clawed her fingers into her palms to keep from showing it. 'Who's the bigger fool now?' she wondered, angry with her self.

Comment: Don't overdo it. I've read plenty of stories in which the two characters were basically destined for each other, yet it appeared that they were just too dumb to realize that for the most part of the book.

Answer (score 2):

It depends really. If this a book that takes place over a couple of days then it may not be 100% realistic to say that she falls in love over a few days. However, the book could take years of character development and exploration of the characters so then it could be realistic.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite series are the ones where it takes multiple books to fall in love, all while the characters are getting closer and closer.

I myself am writing a fantasy series with an underlying romance, and I finished the first draft of the first book a few days ago. (By the way, thanks to everyone on this website for helping me out. I never would have been able to finish it without you.)

Anyway, in the first book my two of the six main characters that are supposed to fall in love are only friends, and start showing a bit deeper care for each other in book two. In book three it’s clear that one of the characters likes the other, and in book four one of the characters is captured and tortured, so then the other character goes to rescue him and realizes she loves him. Then at the end of book four they become bf and gf, and I continue on with my series.

That is just an example, and you don’t have to do exactly that, it varies for each author, book, and series, but I personally enjoy long, drawn out romances.

Answer (score 1):

One novel is definitely enough, but a word to the wise: in order to write about something as profound as falling in love the writer must be fully invested to uncovering the phenomenon he or she writes about, otherwise one can expect piffle and nothing worth being called literary.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen, but you have to develop the relationship carefully to make it seem more realistic.

Since I'm assuming that this is going to be a series, develop the relationship slowly. Start with her just simply thinking that he is a good guy, and then further develop stronger feelings for her.

You also need to show why she likes him, to make it seem more realistic. Maybe she likes him because he is kind. Or maybe because he has some admirable traits.

Also, include a few chapters or scenes where the relationship gets stronger. This could be a deep conversation.

Remember to show the character's whirling of feelings if she is "over-the-heels" for him. Think of the emotions you feel when you are madly in love with someone.